# Convert datetime list from string format to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime, split

I am trying to convert list of datatime objects given in form a string to individual datetime objects.

```
e.g. x = "[datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 26, 0, 0)]"
```

I tried using 'ast.literal_eval(x)' and then I can use strftime to get the format, but ast.literal throws **'ValueError: malformed string'** error.

How do I extract datetime from this ?

Comment: `literal_eval()` only supports specific literals. How did you get that list in the first place? Can you use a different format instead?

Comment: yes I understand why it is throwing that error, no I read this from DB which contains the above as text format. I was not sure how to get proper list out of this.

Comment: Why would it create datetime objects and then stringify them? You could look to use regular expressions here and re-create your datetimes.

Comment: No idea, the DB I have been asked to use contains the above given 'x' as text format, so when I read it from DB I get a string which I need to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ast.literal_eval()` is specifically very limited in what types it supports. You'd be better off serialising your data to a different format, so don't use `str(inputlist)` but find some other serialisation.

If you are stuck with the current format, you could use a regex:

```
from datetime import datetime
import re

dt_constructor = re.compile(r'datetime\.datetime\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)')

result = [datetime(*map(int, group)) for group in dt_constructor.findall(x)]
```

The regular expression extracts the numeric arguments in the string for each `datetime.datetime()` call, and converts those to integers before passing them to the `datetime()` constructor.

Demo:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import re
>>> dt_constructor = re.compile(r'datetime\.datetime\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)')
>>> x = "[datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 26, 0, 0)]"
>>> [datetime(*map(int, group)) for group in dt_constructor.findall(x)]
[datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 14, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 4, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 5, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 26, 0, 0)]
```